# How to use cyrillic characters in route parameters without transliteration?

Tags: routes, symfony, cyrillic

I have a truble with cyrillic in symfony 3.1

I have next route:

```
group_content:
path:     /{name}/{subgroup}
defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Group:showSchedule", subgroup: 1 }
methods:  [ GET ]
requirements:
      name: ".+"
```

and I do in controller next thing:

```
public function showScheduleAction($name, $subgroup)
{
    dump($name); 
    // other unimportant code goes here
}
```

I pass 'тест' as name parameter and dump shows me next:

[image: dump result]

how to use russin letters in route parameters without transliteration?

Thanks!

UPD: I have this error only on IIS 10, if I run this code on linux-server it's work fine.

Comment: It should work out of the box, I just tried it with symfony 3.0.6 and it worked. Can you try to just echo it instead of using `dump`?

Comment: sorry, I try it on windows host and have this error, but on linux host it's work fine. I runing symfony unedr IIS (localy with windows 10)